# Eureka Forms for iOS - variable row height?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, eureka-forms

All --

I’ve just started using [Eureka forms builder](https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka) on an iOS project, and it has a lot of wonderful features.  It’s very nicely done.

However, I eventually realized that there doesn’t seem to be a good way to customize the **Height** of any given row.  [Interestingly, in the Example app, many different rows demonstrating different features are all the same height.]

Granted I can override heightForRowAtIndexPath (which I’ve tried) ... but rows (and indexes) get added dynamically when they’re hidden and unhidden, which makes things more complicated.

Before getting into even more workarounds for this: Is there a simpler / more elegant way of adjusting individual row heights within the framework itself?

I’d like to set the height of any given row within the definition of each Row, or its `.cellSetup`, `.cellUpdate` or similar closures.

[image]

Or even better, is there a straightforward way to have the UITableView respect the **‘intrinsic’** dimensions of only those labels which are used, according to the actual font sizes used?  In other words, if the font in a given row is smaller, that row height should be correspondingly less.

Your help very much appreciated at this point.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

try with this

```
 <<< TextRow().cellSetup({ (cell, row) in
                cell.height = ({return 10})
            })
```

this will change the height, I Hope this helps you

Comment: Thank you so much.  It looks like this needs to happen under `.cellUpdate`, (rather than `.cellSetup`).  But I never would have figured out the syntax without your help.  I’m very appreciative.  Thanks!

Comment: @rondoagogo Is something wrong with the answer? can I help you?

Comment: No, your answer was very helpful!  I’m just waiting to see if anyone has an idea about automatically respecting the ‘intrinsic’ dimensions first.

Comment: Well the intrinsic dimensions are bounded to the type of cells defined by the framework, I think, if you need an specific cells you must create your own type of cells, with your own requirements.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense, thanks.  Again, I appreciate your very helpful answers (and am awarding you the bounty).  Thank you again very much!

Comment: your answer work most of the time but height not being updated occasionally, how about that?

Comment: @nova within `.cellUpdate` call `row.reload()`

Comment: @LeonMak you're a lifesaver! in my case calling `row.reload()` in `.cellUpdate` alongside with calling `$0.cell.height = { UITableView.automaticDimension }` into row's `init` closure makes it work

Answer (score 0):

#### Update the cell's height:

```swift
TextRow.cellUpdate { cell, row in
   cell.height = { 10 }
}
```